# How to store html code in string using jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

When I use this it works-

```
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils" %>
<%@ include file="testingconnection.jsp" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%
String test=StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4("<h1>hello</h1>");
```

But as soon as I introduce "quotes" it doesn't.

```
String test2=StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4("<div class="text-center"> <h1 >hello</h1></div>");
```

I know "quotes" stands for beginning and ends.
Is there a workaround? I need to store html content in mysql database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add escape character `\` before inner quotes.

```
String test2=StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4("<div class=\"text-center\"> <h1 >hello</h1></div>");
```

Comment: My html is very long I cannot just put \. before inner quotes.

Comment: you can automatize this process with string replace according to suitable regex.